# Operator ~ in c programming language

Tags: c, operators

How does `~` operator work in c?

can anyone explain the following code?

```
main()
{
   printf("%d",~5);
}
```

output is `-6`

Comment: Related: wiki page on [bitwise NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT).

Comment: This should be covered in your handy C reference manual.  If you don't have a handy C reference manual, I recommend Harbison & Steele's [C: A Reference Manual](http://careferencemanual.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ~ operator in c is the NOT bitwise operator.  So, in your example

```
   main()
{
       printf("%d",~5);
}
```

will print

```
-6
```

The bits work as follows.

5 = 0000 0101

When you take the NOT of a byte you flip all the 1's and 0's making the new number

-6 = 1111 1010.

Comment: Note that it doesn't *always* have to result in `-6`. I.e. on systems using one's complement integers, the result is `-5`. On sign-magnitude systems, the result could be something like `-65530`.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen is right.  I just used -6 because that's what C defaulted to when I ran it.

Answer (score 7):

`5` is (probably) a 32-bit signed integer with bit representation `0x00000005`, or in binary:

```
0b00000000000000000000000000001010
```

`~5` is the bitwise NOT of `5`, which will be `0xFFFFFFFA`, or in binary:

```
0b11111111111111111111111111110101
```

Using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), that is `-6`.

Comment: Note that I say that `5` is *probably` 32-bit because based on the C standard, an `int` does not have to be 32 bits. It only has to be equal to or greater than the size of `short`, which has to be 16 bits or more.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard

> 4 The result of the ~ operator is the bitwise complement of its
>   (promoted) operand (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only
>   if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set). The
>   integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has
>   the promoted type. If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the
>   expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that
>   type minus E.

So if you have 5 and sizeof( int ) is equal to 4 then you will have

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101 => 5
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111010 => ~5 == -6
```

if you would use `unsigned int` instead of `int`,for example

```
int main( void )
{
   printf("%u", ~5u );
}
```

then as it is said in the quote

> If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the  expression ~E is
>   equivalent to the maximum value representable in that  type minus E.

you would get. The maximum unsigned int value is

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 => UINT_MAX
-
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101 => 5
=
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111010 => UINT_MAX - 5u
```

Answer (score 0):

The ~ operator is bitwise NOT, it inverts the bits in a binary number:

so when we convert 5 into binary 5=0101

Then the NOT 0101 means 1010=-6. Basically ~ is used to represent bitwise NOT.

So the answer is -6.