# ~symbol before hexadecimal number

Tags: c++, c, symbols

I'm checking a code written a long time ago.

I don't know what's the meaning of **~** symbol before the hexadecimal number.

It's like:

```
a = b & ~0xff;
```

Other parts of the code are like below, without the **~** symbol:

```
a = (b & 0xff00) >> 8;
```

Comment: `~` is a unary operator, similar to `-` or `!`.

Comment: Why do you downvote this question? It is an absolutely valid question, even if of low niveau.

Comment: It wasn't me - but OP could have easily looked up the operators reference guide.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Maybe because looking at any tutorial, book or reference would have answered that question, which means it "shows no research-effort"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator ~ in c programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185884/operator-in-c-programming-language)

Comment: @Deduplicator that really shows my low level of knowledge. I did research, but by symbol, not by operator.

Comment: @MartinR I agree it can be duplicated question

Comment: @MartinR I didn't found that question because I didn't look for operator before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `~` operator is the bitwise NOT, it inverts the bits of a binary number.

Comment: Note: if operand is `char`, `short`, etc., it is promoted to `int/unsigned` and then the bits are flipped.

Comment: @chux This is the case for all operations. Note that the promotion always goes to `signed int`, never to `unsigned int`.

Comment: @FUZxxl "promotion always goes to signed int, never to unsigned int" is not so.  "If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`." C11dr §6.3.1.1 2

Comment: this does only happen on very exotic architectures, but you are right.